# Does an autowired FluentProducerTemplate need to have its headers and body cleared before use within same service?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, olingo

Autowired FluentProducerTemplate in a service bean will intermittently have a header set from a previous call in another method in the same service bean. I set the CamelOlingo4.keyPredicate is the header in this case.

```
    FluentProducerTemplate producerTemplate;


UserAccount account = producerTemplate
                .withHeader("CamelOlingo4.$select", "cva_useraccountid,statuscode,emailaddress,cva_firstname,cva_lastname,cva_password,cva_lastlogout,cva_lastlogin,cva_lastloginattempt,cva_lockeduntil,cva_loginattemptcount,_cva_contact_value")
                .withHeader("email",username)
                .withHeader("activeStatus",MSDynamicsAccountStatusCodes.ACTIVE.toString())
                .withHeader("lockedStatus",MSDynamicsAccountStatusCodes.LOCKED.toString())
                .to("direct:login")
                .request(UserAccount.class);
```

And my route definition:

```
from("direct:login")
            .id("routes.id.login")
            .toD("olingo4://read/{{route.login}}?$filter=emailaddress eq '${header.email}' and (statuscode eq ${header.activeStatus} or statuscode eq ${header.lockedStatus})").log("Response from Olingo: ${body}")
            .process(new OlingoProcessor());
```

I do fire an async request route with the keyPredicate upon successful login...

```
producerTemplate
        .withHeader("CamelOlingo4.keyPredicate", userId)
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .withBody(user)
        .to("direct:tracklogin")
        .asyncSend();
```

And route defined for track:login:

```
from("direct:tracklogin")
            .id("routes.id.track.login")
            .marshal()
            .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .log("JSON Body: ${id} ${body}")
            .to("olingo4://patch/{{route.patch.track-login}}");
```

Random times, the "direct:login" route will have the keyPredicate set in the header, causing an error in my OlingoProcessor, since I'mn not getting the expected object back from the exchange body. (Olingo Object is different when querying with a keyPredicate)

Not sure if the issue lies with my implementation, the camel-olingo4 comp or the FluentProducerTemplate itself... But I do see there is a clearAll() method on the FluentProducerTemplate. I'm suspecting i need to call it whenever i use the autowired producer template within the same service bean. Just need some confirmation...

Answer (score 3):

As Spring default scope is **singleton**, indeed the injected producer template bean instance will be reused, and the clearAll() should be called before setting headers, body, etc...

Of course, another possible solution would be to create each time a brand new producer template instance:

```
FluentProducerTemplate producerTemplate = context.createFluentProducerTemplate();
UserAccount account = producerTemplate.withHeader(...)
```

Comment: Thanks @tachedechoco ... so how will this behave in a spring boot web application with multiple threads? I believe i read in the docs that FluentProducerTemplate is thread safe, so that means that its methods are synchronized to prevent multiple threads clobbering each others headers?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

> Does an autowired FluentProducerTemplate need to have its headers and body cleared before use within same service?

In Camel 2, yes. In Camel 3, no.

**Long Story**

The [CamelAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot/blob/master/core/camel-spring-boot/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.java#L176) from Camel's Spring Boot Starter create a `FluentProducerTemplate` with no specific scope, hence Spring's default scope singleton is applied and you have only one instance per application.

The `FluentProducerTemplate` is thread-safe. In Camel 2, thread-safety is achieved by storing the message body and headers in `ThreadLocal`s. If you don't clear the headers after/before usage you may occasionally see left-overs from previous invocations. So, yes, you'd have to call `clearHeader()` or `clearAll()` manually.

The situation in Camel 3 is a bit more relaxed. There, thread-safety is achieved by producing new instances of `FluentProducerTemplate` whenever you call a method that would otherwise modify the template (headers, body). Clearing the values is not strictly necessary anymore as far as I can tell.